# How to convert string to this type of list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using a library, that is returning a Python list.

When I print that list it looks like this:

```
print(face_locations)
```

```
[(92, 254, 228, 118), (148, 661, 262, 547)]
```

```
print(type(face_locations))
```

```
<class 'list'>
```

I have a string with values: `"92 254 228 118;148 661 262 547"`.

I want to convert this string to the same datatype.

What I did so far:

```
face_locations= "92 254 228 118;148 661 262 547"
face_locations= face_locations.split(";")
for i in range(len(face_locations)):
    face_locations[i] = face_locations[i].split(" ")
```

Both are lists...But When I run this function later in my code, I get an error:

```
for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings): 
    ....do something
```

Comment: please show us the error and exactly what you need

Comment: There should be no error, other than the length of `face_encodings` and `face_locations` are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension and map the elements of `str` to `int`.

```
face_locations= "92 254 228 118;148 661 262 547"
face_locations= face_locations.split(";")
[tuple(map(int, elem.split(' '))) for elem in face_locations]
```

Output:

```
[(92, 254, 228, 118), (148, 661, 262, 547)]
```

Answer (score 1):

beer44 has a great answer and just to show how much work map saves:

```
face_locations = "92 254 228 118;148 661 262 547"
face_locations = face_locations.split(";")
face_locations = [face_locations[x].split(' ') for x in range(len(face_locations))]
for sublist in face_locations:
    for i in range(len(sublist)):
        sublist[i] = int(sublist[i])
face_locations = [tuple(sublist) for sublist in face_locations]
```

Output:

```
[(92, 254, 228, 118), (148, 661, 262, 547)]
```

Comment: My understanding is that map is a little bit faster than list comprehensions but in this case the nested for loops (I couldn't come up with a list comprehension for the str to int conversion) would slow it down even more. Could make a large dataset and test it I suppose, might be interesting.